# Stripe charged total amount

Tags: stripe-payments

The Stripe **home dashboard** (not payments, transfers, or customers but when you first login...) shows "gross volume" total which is calculated by totaling all of the successful charges together within the given time period. With the current limiting of a maximum of 100 records, this proves to be difficult when querying for several days worth of data. Meanwhile their internal dashboard endpoint does this fairly effortlessly:

`https://dashboard.stripe.com/v1/charts/gross_volume?start_time=1487635200&end_time=1488239999`

```
{
  "currency": "usd",
  "data": [...],
  "estimated": false,
  "total": 123456, //gross volume total
  "unit": "day"
}
```

*NOTE: The above endpoint is **not offered** in the [Stripe API documents](https://stripe.com/docs/api) as far as I can tell. I'm looking for an alternative solution.*

Is there a better / best practice to retrieve the data that's provided at this endpoint using one of the resources in [the given documents](https://stripe.com/docs/api)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Balance Transaction API](https://stripe.com/docs/api#balance_history) with [auto-pagination](https://stripe.com/docs/api#auto-pagination) to get at all of the information.

By expanding `data.source`, `data.source.customer` and `data.source.balance_transaction` you will have access to all of the information that makes up that Transfer Summary Dashboard page.

Comment: Sorry, I realize I should have been more specific about which dashboard...

Comment: Auto-pagination over 'List Charges' will get you that number - but so would Balance Transactions.

Or you can listen for the Charge-related webhooks (https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks) and tally it up yourself.